# Lost files in Windows 10, but only in one folder tree and timestamped after specific date?

Tags: windows-10, file-recovery

What might cause all files and folders after a certain timestamp to vanish from a folder and its subtree?

My daughter's computer has two disks: C and D. Windows installed on C. Some apps installed on D instead of C due to limited space on C.

After a hardware upgrade we performed a reinstall of Windows using "Reset this PC". We chose "Remove everything", which seems to have correctly quick(?) formatted C but left D intact. She continued using the computer, reinstalling several games, drawing tools etc.

This eventing, about a week after the reinstall, she looked for the first time after reinstall in a D folder where she regularly saves all her drawings and other files. To her horror it contains nothing dated after year 2019.

We've made sure her user account has full access to the D disk, including this folder, and that we're seing all files, including hidden and system files.

We've also searched the entire C and D disks for folders with that name (as well as the name of one of the most critical subfolders), but nothing was found. That check seemed relevant in case she accidentally dragged the folder to some random place without noticing, but I fail to understand how that would affect only newer files and not older ones.

Any ideas what might have happened or can suggest any actions that might help us recover the lost files?

(We are working on retrieving from backup, which is unfortunately a bit complicated for unrelated reasons, including lack of time for important system maintenance, which also possibly means that this particular folder might be missing from the backup. Hence this question...)

Comment: I think if you installed programs and data in drive D: after Windows was first set up (normal) that the Reset would have ignored drive D:

Comment: Did you move all the special folders like Desktop, Documents, Pictures, Downloads etc. to the D: drive?

Comment: "we performed a reinstall of Windows" - why? Windows 10 is quite good in recognizing new hardware. Lesson learned: Always make a backup of the data before a Windows installation. Also make backups regularly.

Comment: @John Yes, the reset ignored D:. A lot of other folders remain intact, including newer ones.

Comment: @ThomasWeller We did not fiddle with the special/library folders. The reinstall was not primarily due to the hardware upgrade. More like it was time to do a cleanup. She had been having some odd issues with some things (unrelated to that folder and unrelated to drawing tools).

Comment: Fwiw one of our backups seem to have covered the lost files, so the problem is probably solved now. I am wondering if the loss was caused by a "manual mistake", e.g. dragging to the wrong location and interrupting the copy/move operation, then removing the files from the (incorrect) target location, not realizing they would have been already removed from the source, and that the operation for some reason started with newest files first. I guess we'll never know.

Answer (score 1):

> My daughter's computer has two disks: C and D. Windows installed on C.
> Some apps installed on D instead of C due to limited space on C.

Splitting Windows into two drives often causes issues.

**So three things:**

(A) In this case, the Reset ignored Drive D: because it was not looking for it as a source for Windows Apps or even data if not looking to see Windows data on another drive. It depends, but I never saw it as safe.

Always have a good backup.

(B) Better for the long term to install a bigger HDD or SSD drive in the laptop so that Windows and all regular data goes on Drive C:  Make sure data stored on another drive is always backed up.

(C) A Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Everything (using one Windows drive for Programs and Apps) is a much safer way to repair issues.

I have seen a number of cases like this.

Comment: It's not a laptop, but I guess that's beside the point. The system was upgraded with a second disk, it only had a single one to begin with. The purpose of that added disk was to be able to install large games like Overwatch and Fortnite there. Apparently she also moved her drawings and other files of her own creation to a folder on that disk, without my knowledge. I have never heard that it would be problematic to install apps to secondary disks. Windows itself was never split. Backup: Yes, I'm fully aware that I should have been more proactive there. I'm in the process of getting on top of it

Comment: A Repair Install will keep all data and a better way to fix things. I made some clarifications to my post.